# Excel template in sharepoint - how to open as a new file from template?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, templates

I need to place an excel template in sharepoint and give people a link to it. I would like to prevent users from changing the template. I do not want users to save any file in the library. There are couple of solutions:
- revoke people sharepoint right to change the file,
- keep the file checked-out to me.

I also think about other scenario. Currently file is in `.xlsm` format (macro enabled workbook) but I am thinking about `.xltm` (macro enabled workbook template) as a way of forcing client excels to treat the file as template only. It looks like excel stubbornly wants to save the file (downloaded from sharepoint) as a template in source location and not as the new file. Only when I open the template directly from my local drive do I get what I need.
How do I force sharepoint/excel to use `.xltm` file stored in sharepoint as a template for a new file?

Isn't it a matter of incorrect http content disposition header?

Comment: "How do I force sharepoint/excel to use `.xstm` file stored in sharepoint?" - shouldn't that be `.xltm`?

Comment: Good comment, extension corrected, thanks

Comment: NB: you might get more responses here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ - this isn't really a programming question

Comment: Best thing would be to have all stackoverflow.com questions that are  tagged with "sharepoint" linked automatically on the site you mentioned :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reference the template file using a file path rather than the HTML path, it should open as a new document, rather than opening the original template e.g. use

```
\\SiteCollection\Site\DocumentLibrary\Template.xltx
```

instead of

```
http://SiteCollection/Site/DocumentLibrary/Template.xltx
```

Comment: New problem appeared as it looks like it is not possible to send such links in html email... :(

Answer (score 2):

In some cases making your Excel file a template for a content type or a library will do want you want. If you set some document library a template file this way all your new files in this library will be created from this file. Check out the Advanced Settings of a document library. There is a section Document Template that does the trick. If this section is disabled then your library has Content Types Management enabled and this means that you have to check the Advanced settings of a content type to set the template.

This solution makes all new files be created in the document library but not on a desktop but if you can live with that please be kind to mark as an answer.

Comment: unfortunately I need all new files to be local (or even temporary) and not saved in library; library is just a central storage of templates; template is some kind of a form - it is filled hundreds times a month - storing it is not needed as form data is saved in database using macros; only annoyance now is the "document is in read-only mode" yellow ribbon while opening the file from sharepoint...

Comment: That sounds pretty much like Infopath. Wht don't you implement an Infopath form to host in SharePoint and make the form submit data to the database via web service?

Comment: Templates were created much before infopath was introduced (1999). I doubt client is willing to pay for a complete redesign of the template  but still thanks for the tip - I will check infopath capabilities for future use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a link that can be sent out using mails you can use:
`http://SiteCollection/Site/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=%2FSite%2FDocumentLibrary%2Template%2Exltx`